# Modeling the multiplication of two binary decision variables in undirected graph in python

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, python

In an undirected graph, I'm trying to model a constraint that forcing the optimizer to set an edge $(u,v)$ between two nodes to only exist (= $1$) if the two nodes have been selected to be $1$. The three decision variables can be something like that:

$z(u,v) \geq y_u x_v$ , $\quad x,y,z \in \{0,1\}$

and to linearize the multiplication here, I'm introducing a new decision variable $r=xy$ and these constraints has been added:

$z(u,v) \geq r(u,v)$

$r(u,v) \leq y_u$

$r(u,v) \leq x_v$

$r(u,v) \geq y_u + x_v -1$

Keeping in mind that this is for undirected graph where $r(u,v)$ is different from $r(v,u)$. How can I model this in Python using **Pulp** and **NetworkX** ?

Comment: Do you instead mean *directed* graph?

Comment: No, I actually meant it (undirected graph), that is why I'm confused about modeling that constraint

Comment: Hmm, $r(u,v)$ is different from $r(v,u)$ usually means directed.  Is it maybe bipartite?  If not, why do you have both $x$ and $y$ variables?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, x and y at two different levels, I forgot to mention that I'm solving a hierarchical problem

Comment: Is you question just how to implement the set of constraints you describe in python using the two mentioned tools?

Comment: Yes, actually I'm confused about the fact that edge$( u, v) $ is the same as edge $(v, u) $ for my consideration in undirected graph and how to overcome this in coding.

Comment: So is $z(1,2) = z(2,1)$ supposed to be 1 only if $y_1 = x_2 = 1$, only if $y_2 = x_1 = 1$, or only if either condition is met?

Comment: I'm suppose to have either it is $z(2,1)$ or $z(1,2) = 1$ when both $y$ and $x$ $=1 $

Comment: Do you want to model $z(1,2) = x_1\cdot y_2$ and $z(2,1) = x_2\cdot y_1$? Or do you want to model $x_1\land y_2 \lor x_2\land y_1 \Leftrightarrow z(1,2) \lor z(2,1)$? Or do you just have either the variable $z(1,2)$ or the variable $z(2,1)$, as it represents a directed edge and you want this one variable to be active when one of the $x_1y_2, x_2,y_1$ is $1$?

Comment: I have undirected edge, so both $z(1,2)$ and $z(2,1)$ are referring to the same edge., and I would like to have z$(1,2)$ and z(2,1) $=1$ when  $x_1 \cup y_2 $ or  $x_2 \cup y_1)$ $=1$ ,
My problem is that $z$ is defined as edge and $y$ and $x$ are defined as nodes, So when I constraint say $z(1,2)$ by nodes $y_1$ and $x_2$, the optimizer is violating the constraint by choosing $y_2$ and $x_1$.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just constraint it by both?

Comment: Addition: If you define a new decision variable r=xy then the model is still not linear. You could do x+y-1 <= 2*z instead. (Assuming that z is implicitly or explicitly minimized)